# temporary dns error inet_e_resource_not_found

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, dns, microsoft-edge

I wondered if I can pick your brains with a project we have and see if you have maybe experienced this issue?

Basically we have a new site which is on...

https://securetronics.co.uk

---

temporary dns error inet_e_resource_not_found

http://prntscr.com/kjss65

But for some reason sometimes on chrome and edge it comes up with this error and I have no clue as to what is happening! It is a new one for me and can’t fathom out what could be the cause! I don’t think it is the website and everything I Google is coming up with it saying it’s a browser issue.

It comes on but then vanishes if refreshed and won’t appear for ages, but say like day after etc it comes back?

The problem is that my clients site is an eCommerce site so if any of his potential customers go to the site from the browser and it comes up with that error they are going to be put off instantly!

Any help would be appreciated as I am at a loss here!

Thank you

Chris

Comment: DNS issues like this one are usually a problem with your device, not with the website itself. Try browsing your website from another device (smartphone, another computer) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: yeah i cant find the issue on my pc but it was my client who spotted it and we tried on another computer Mac on chrome it popped up then vanished after 5 seconds and another on edge it showed up.

Comment: Were these other devices (Mac and PC) connected under the same network?

Comment: In our office yeah they were. im not 100% sure what network the client was on but it wasn't in our office when he saw the error